# the barcode scan library doesn't work on iOS but it does on Android

Tags: codenameone

I try to use this librairy to use the barcode scanner on iOS : https://github.com/codenameone/cn1-codescan It works very well on Android but when my application opens the same barcode scanner form on iOS, my application just shuts down without displaying any error message.
I have to scan Code 128 bar codes.
Perhaps that I have to edit the property especially for IOS ?

Here is my code :

```
public class ScanCode extends Form {
final Container cnt = this;
public ScanCode(Form parent){
    this.setLayout(new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    Display.getInstance().setProperty("android.scanTypes", "CODE_128");
    CodeScanner.getInstance().scanBarCode(new ScanResult() {
        public void scanCompleted(String contents, String formatName, byte[] rawBytes) {
            String word;
            word= contents.substring(0,12);
            List<Patient> myList= new ArrayList<>();
            myList= RestManager.getList(contents.substring(0,12));
            if(myList.size()==0){
                new ManualInfo(parent,contents).show();
            }
            else{
                Date date = new Date();
                Intervention intervention = new Intervention();
                intervention.setList(myList.get(0));
                intervention.setDateAction(date);
                intervention.setDateCreate(date);
                intervention.setDateUpdate(date);
                intervention.setEncodingType(Intervention.BARCODE_TYPE);
                Update ajoutintervention = new Update();
                ajoutintervention.setId((long) 0);
                ajoutintervention.setDatas(intervention.toJson());
                ajoutintervention.setDateCreate(date);
                ajoutintervention.setDateUpdate(date);
                ajoutintervention.setTreatment(String.valueOf(Constants.INSERT));
                ajoutintervention.setDone(String.valueOf(false));
                ajoutintervention.setClassName(intervention.getName());
                ajoutintervention.setParam(myList.get(0).getWord());
                DatabaseHelper.saveDataClass(ajoutintervention);
            }

        }

        public void scanCanceled() {
            cnt.addComponent(new Label("cancelled"));
        }

        public void scanError(int errorCode, String message) {
            cnt.addComponent(new Label("err " + message));
        }
    });        
}
```

**EDIT:**
Here is the build hints :

```
codename1.arg.ios.add_libs=ExternalAccessory.framework;CoreBluetooth.framework;libc++.dylib;SystemConfiguration.framework;,libc++.dylib,CoreText.framework,MessageUI.framework,CoreVideo.framework,CoreMedia.framework    
codename1.arg.ios.background_modes=,bluetooth-central,bluetooth-peripheral
codename1.arg.ios.debug.archs=arm64
codename1.arg.ios.includePush=true
codename1.arg.ios.newStorageLocation=true
codename1.arg.ios.plistInject=<key>NSBluetoothPeripheralUsageDescription</key><string>This app uses a BLE cardreader</string><key>UISupportedExternalAccessoryProtocols</key><array><string>bt.reader.library</string></array> <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key> <dict><key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key><true/></dict>   
codename1.arg.ios.pods.platform=8.0,7.0
codename1.arg.ios.pods.sources=https\://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git
codename1.arg.ios.xcode_version=10.1
codename1.arg.java.version=8
```

I work on a 12.1 iOS version and the device is an iPad Air.

Comment: Which build hints do you have on the device, which OS and device version?

Comment: I've edited my question to answer you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your cn1lib is up to date and that you ran it on the simulator as well. You need to define the `ios.NSCameraUsageDescription` build hint (or `codename1.arg.ios.NSCameraUsageDescription` if you edit the file directly). This is required by current versions of iOS. The library adds this implicitly when you run the code in the simulator.